Progress 4GL - SYSTEM ERROR: Index oid_sd_det in tt_temp for recid 3747514 partition 0 could not be deleted. (17630)
I am getting below error after dump and load data from a table(int32) to the same table(int64) and run the program. Any Idea how to solve this?
SYSTEM ERROR: Index oid_sd_det in tt_temp for recid 3747514 partition 0 could not be deleted. (17630)

There are many possible cause for that error. There are often also other messages associated with the error which help to narrow the field of possible causes.
It is also important to know which specific version of OpenEdge is involved.
Additionally, it is also helpful to know the table schema and index definitions for the table.
Finally, if the problem is repeatable, knowing what code triggers the error is a big help.
Lacking such information, a good generic guide to debugging the error can be found here: https://community.progress.com/s/article/P106594
BTW - tables do not have "int32" and "int64" properties. Integer fields might be int32 or int64 and you might convert from int32 to int64 by dumping a table containing such a field and then reloading it. Knowing what specific steps you took to accomplish this might also be relevant.
